Are all TCAS targets on view?
Using TCAS II, are all targets visible? or only when they could get in conflict with own aircraft and suposse a threat?

Seems the same as What is the range of TCAS?, there are subtleties explained in the answer (Diversity of ranges)

Other targets are also available. The details may depend on the aircraft and exact TCAS implementation installed. Here are some examples for the Boeing 777:

TCAS Traffic Display

1 Traffic Targets
Indicates relative position of traffic.

filled red square indicates a resolution advisory (RA)
filled amber circle indicates a traffic advisory (TA)
filled white diamond indicates proximate traffic
unfilled white diamond indicates other traffic


(Boeing 777 FCOMv2 15.10.9 Warning Systems - TCAS Traffic and TCAS Alert Message TRAFFIC Display)
As you can see, also proximate traffic and other traffic may be shown as filled or unfilled diamonds respectively. Proximate traffic is defined as closer than 6 NM and within 1200 ft vertically (or with unknown altitude), but not RA or TA.
Sometimes, it is also possible to filter aircraft shown by relative altitude, e.g.:

TCAS Controls (Transponder Panel)

2 TCAS Airspace Switch
ABOVE – altitude reporting traffic from 2,700 feet below to 9,000 feet above
current altitude displayed.
NORM (normal) – altitude reporting traffic from 2,700 feet below to 2,700 feet
above current altitude displayed.
BELOW – altitude reporting traffic 9,000 feet below to 2,700 feet above current
altitude displayed.

(Boeing 777 FCOMv2 15.10.5 Warning Systems - Traffic Alert and Collision Avoidance System (TCAS))
